# Crash when assigning local object to dataSource of UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have the following setter defined in my class that extends `UICollectionView`:

```
// @interface ClipsDataSource : NSObject <UICollectionViewDataSource>

- (void)setProject:(Project *)project
{
    _project = project;

    ClipsDataSource *dataSource = [[ClipsDataSource alloc] initWithCollectionView:self];
    dataSource.delegate = self;
    dataSource.fetchedResultsController = project.clipsResultsController;

    self.dataSource = dataSource;
}
```

When I run my application I get the following exception:

```
-[CALayerArray numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x174245490
```

I realised that the instance pointer is the address of the local variable I had used in my setter; the class name is obviously random. From this "discovery" I reasoned that the object was released after assignment.

Normally Xcode will warn me about these issues by saying:

> Assigning retained object to unsafe property; object will be released after assignment.

And, sure enough, I see that warning if I change my code to this:

```
self.dataSource = [[ClipsDataSource alloc] initWithCollectionView:self];
```

I have two questions:

1. Why doesn't Xcode show a warning?
2. Why is `.dataSource` considered an unsafe property? It's defined as `(nonatomic, assign)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***1) Why doesn't Xcode show a warning?***

Because clang is not intelligent enough to figure out that your datasource instance will not be retained elsewhere; only this obvious case will be reported:

```
self.dataSource = [[ClipsDataSource alloc] initWithCollectionView:self];
```

***2) Why is .dataSource considered an unsafe property? It's defined as (nonatomic, assign).***

This is done to prevent retain cycles with self referential constructs, which happens quite often in `ViewController` code.

Imagine that your `CollectionViewController` is the datasource of `CollectionView`,

```
self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
```

This means:

- `CollectionViewController` retains `.collectionView`, because View Controllers retain their views by default.
- `CollectionView` retains it's datasource (which is `CollectionViewController`).

This will cause a retain cycle and therefore Apple decided to use unsafe unretained pointer for `.datasource`.

Note that both `assign` and `weak` pointers will not retain the object that they are pointing. The difference between them is that `weak` will be automatically nullified when the referenced object is deallocated.

But `assign` pointer will NOT be nullified, so it will continue pointing to address of memory. Further dereference of that pointer (after deallocation) will probably cause `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, or you will get another object (as another object can be written in that address after deallocation).

Comment: Hmm, I'm not using a `CollectionViewController` .. so not sure how that applies.

Comment: are you using MVC architecture?

Comment: The code I've shown just concerns itself with things related to `UICollectionView`; as such, it sets itself as the delegate of the data source to decorate cells.

Comment: I would like to know more about the unsafe unretained pointers you've mentioned though; does `(assign)` imply unsafe? The absence of `(weak)` made me think it would retain objects assigned to it.

Comment: both `assign` and `weak` will not retain the object, difference between `weak` and `assign` is that `weak` is automatically nullified when object is deallocated, but `assign` pointer will NOT be nullified, so it will continue keeping address of memory, so after dereference you will probably get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, or you will get another object (as another object can be written in that address after dealocation).

Comment: Also confusion, why datasource/delegate of `UICollectionView` is not retained (it's not strong/retain) because at 99% iOS Application are being written in MVC architecture, in this case datasource/delegate is assigned to controller, so this means controller retains it's view, and view retains controller (via delegate/datasource pointer), so this will cause retain cycle.

Comment: Actually, my confusion came from the misunderstanding of what `(assign)` means; I understand why the property can't be `(strong)` though :)